# Validating multipart/form-data in Spring REST api

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, multipartform-data

I recently came up to an issue related to validation. Typically, I am building a REST api that allow users to create their account including avatars. All of the information should be submitted  when user clicks to Register button. So, my server will then receive a request that includes some fields like `name (string), birthday (datetime), ... and avatar (multipart file)`. So, the question is how to validate the received file is a truly image and has an allowed size and simultaneously validate that the others (email, password) are also valid.

For the case that all fields is text, we can easily validate them using the combination of annotations like this

Controller

```java
@PostMapping(path = "")
public ResponseEntity<?> createNewAccount(@RequestBody @Valid RegisterRequest registerRequest) {
    Long resourceId = service.createNewCoderAccount(registerRequest);

    return ResponseEntity.created(location(resourceId)).build();
}
```

Request DTO

```java
@ConfirmedPassword
public class RegisterRequest extends BaseRequest implements ShouldConfirmPassword {
    @NotBlank(message = "Field 'email' is required but not be given")
    @Email
    @Unique(message = "Email has been already in use", service = UserValidatorService.class, column = "email")
    private String email;

    @NotBlank(message = "Field 'password' is required but not be given")
    @Size(min = 6, message = "Password should contain at least 6 characters")
    private String password;

    @NotBlank(message = "Field 'confirmPassword' is required but not be given")
    private String confirmPassword;

    @NotBlank(message = "Field 'firstName' is required but not be given")
    private String firstName;

    @NotBlank(message = "Field 'lastName' is required but not be given")
    private String lastName;
}
```

Or in case that the request containing only file(s), we can absolutely do like this

Controller

```java
@PostMapping(path = "/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> editChallengeMetadata(
    @ModelAttribute ChallengeMetadataRequest request,
    BindingResult bindingResult,
    @PathVariable("id") Long id,
    @CurrentUser User user
) throws BindException {
    challengeMetadataRequestValidator.validate(request, bindingResult);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        throw new BindException(bindingResult);
    }

    Long challengeId = service.updateChallengeMetadata(id, request, user);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(RestResponse.build(challengeId, HttpStatus.OK));
}
```

Validator

```java
public class ChallengeMetadataRequestValidator implements Validator {
    @Override
    public boolean supports(@NonNull Class<?> aClass) {
        return ChallengeMetadataRequest.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(@NonNull Object o, @NonNull Errors errors) {
        ChallengeMetadataRequest request = (ChallengeMetadataRequest) o;

        if (request.getBanner() != null && !request.getBanner().isEmpty()) {
            if (!List.of("image/jpeg", "image/png").contains(request.getBanner().getContentType())) {
                errors.rejectValue("banner", "challenge.mime-type.not-supported", new String[]{request.getBanner().getContentType()}, "Mime-type is not supported");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you seen above, if I wrap all data (including avatar) in a DTO class, I definitely write its own validator. But what will happen if then I have to write manually hundreds validators like that.

So, do anyone have any idea about it, typically, make the `multipart/form-data` request becomes simalar with `application/json` request ?

Thanks and regards,